# Proving the monotonicity of a countably additive set function on a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let m be a set function defined for all sets in a $ \sigma$-Algebra $\scr A$ ; Assume that m is countably additive over countable disjoint collections of sets in A , with values in $[0,\infty ]$

Prove that if $A \subseteq\ B$, and $A,B \subseteq\ \scr A\ $, then $m(A) \leq m(B)  $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $B$ as the union of the disjoint sets $A$ and $B-A.$ The latter is also an element of $\mathcal A$ and $m(B-A)\geq0.$

Then

$$m(A)+m(B-A)=m(A\cup(B-A))=m(B)$$

and therefore

$$m(A)=m(B)-m(B-A)\leq m(B).$$

Comment: good catch, m is nonnegative. I edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: This would give $m(B) = m(A) + m(B\backslash A)$. Since m is nonnegative, $m(B) \geq m(A)$. Is this enough for a proof?

Comment: Well done, I will add it to the answer.